# Should a brand new AAV be able to leak water?

Tags: plumbing, repair, leak, sink, garbage-disposal

I know that *ideally*, an AAV (Air admittance valve) would not leak air or water out. But, should it be able to leak water under certain circumstances (such as running the garbage disposal) while still being considered "working"?

Consider a house has just a kitchen sink and dishwasher connected to a stack. Everything else was on a different stack. The kitchen stack was vented to the roof, however it was determined that there was a leak in the pipe to the roof. A plumber disconnected the vent, and placed an AAV under the sink.

The issue here is that if the sink is full of water, and the garbage disposal runs for more than 5 seconds, a decent amount of water leaks out of the AAV.

[image: AAV leak plumbing diagram Rev2]

[image: AAV under sink]

I am reading that AAV's are supposed to be a "one way valve". See diagram below. Air can come in, but the seal should close and not let pressure out...yet water is getting out.

[image: AAV diagram]
(Image from [Amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00V95U9U6))

The plumber who installed the AAV insists that the drain under the basement floor must be to blame, and should be "snaked"/cleaned out. Perhaps it is clogged under the basement, but I'm still wondering if an AAV should leak. I'm thinking that it may help to raise the AAV as much as possible. It's obviously below the flood level of the sink. Maybe it could be routed around the sink, just under the counter top, as seen in the following crude photoshop:

[image: AAV hypothetical reroute]

Is the plumber free to blame the basement drain, or is this AAV dysfunctional?

Comment: If water is reaching an AAV then it is not installed properly Or  you have blockage somewhere,  water should never reach an AAV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manufacturer of the AAV: "It should not leak, even with a garbage disposal running."

I also asked "What if the drain is clogged?". They kind of hemmed and hawed and said "Hmm, it shouldn't really matter."

I will increase the height of the AAV to mitigate leaking, as well as cleaning out the drain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about AAVs (or venting in general). But I do know that disposals push a **LOT** of water (and everything else!) very hard & very fast. If there is a clog in the line then stuff will come out elsewhere - e.g., in my case I have had output from a 2nd sink. So with a low-position AAV, I would not be at all surprised to see the disposal + clogged line overwhelm the AAV and end up with a mess.

Based on a little searching and my own experience (with disposals & dishwashers, but not with AAVs) is that:

- You do likely have a clog in the line, which will need to get snaked or otherwise cleared out, and until that is resolved the AAV is simply not going to stand up to the disposal.
- The AAV, *by design*, just can't keep up with the disposal if the waste line is not running totally free. A regular vent would handle a clog better. However, the AAV should be fine when the line is reasonably clear.

You should also make sure your dishwasher has either an air gap or a high hose loop. Your diagram doesn't show either one. Without an air gap or high hose loop, the disposal discharge backup could go into your dishwasher as well as your AAV.

Comment: Indeed, there doesn't appear to be an airgap or high hose loop. I guess there could be a high hose loop hidden behind the side wall of the under-sink cabinet, I'll have to confirm. Now that you mention air gaps...Could that alone prevent the AAV from leaking when the disposal runs? It seems like it to me, but perhaps I misunderstand how they work. This person from another DIY SE quesiton had water spewing from their air-gap, so I'm assuming it could help: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/27547/how-do-i-keep-water-from-getting-in-and-out-of-a-dishwasher-drain-air-gap

Comment: I have not had an AAV leak in the past but I usually create a loop and position the valve at the absolute top of the space.

Comment: @EdBeal - Can you elaborate on "loop"? I'm not sure the exact shape you are implying. As I understand, an AAV itself should not have a trap, as they are for air only, and water would impede their efficiency.

Comment: 1 - As far as the dishwasher, you want something like my answer to https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/138255/draining-problems-in-dishwasher-is-this-drain-setup-ok/138258#138258  2 - Dishwasher air gap/high loop is similar in some ways to the AAV/venting, but not quite the same. The dishwasher issue is specifically to prevent backflow of dirty water into the dishwasher, and only with an air gap (not a high loop) does it actually involve any outside air. But the purpose of the air in the "air gap" is NOT to add air, but rather to make a "gap". In the case of the AAV/venting you...

Comment: actually are adding air to the system. The AAV (as noted by @EdBeal) should be as high up as possible - this helps prevent or minimize water pressure on the AAV - if the AAV is above the sink drain then backup would come up the drain into the sink instead of trying to go up the AAV. However, with the force of a disposal, even in that case you might end up with some (but less than now because it would be higher up) water trying to get out the AAV. 3 - In any case, dishwasher problem is NOT the issue here (but should get fixed anyway) because this happens even when dishwasher is not running.

Comment: I was taught to create a loop of pipe above the trap level and put the AAV at the top of the loop. In this case the loop would be almost 2' wide and ~12" above the trap with the valve on a t at the top of the loop this provides some additional air space for the valve, if something has back flowed into the valve it may not be closing like it should and may need to be cleaned, you are correct the valve should be 1 way.

Comment: @manassehkatz  - I know the dishwasher is a separate issue but I thinking that the air gap may kill two birds with one stone. Regardless, a high loop will be added if not already there. I think the AAv should be raised and I will report back with results. Also, what do you think about Ed Beal's suggestion of a loop on the AAV? I cannot find a single example of an AAV online with anything other than a straight pipe. I don't think I want backed-up water sitting in the pipe to my AAV.

Comment: @EdBeal 's idea of a loop for the AAV makes sense. Keep in mind that what he is talking about is a few pieces of PVC pipe, not the flexible tube that the dishwasher uses. And it does make sense. Don't worry about standing water in the pipe - if the main drain is clear it will be no different than normal, and if the drain is not clear it will provide some extra buffer space which will help protect the AAV from getting flooded. The dishwasher air gap (or high loop) will protect the dishwasher but won't help with your current problem.

Comment: The loop is used under island sinks where you cannot place the AAV above the sink level or if no vent because of wall material. If I have space and can place the AAV above the highest fixture no loop is needed.

Comment: @manassehkatz / Ed Beal, can it really be advisable to have backed-up water in the loop? I cannot see how that is allowable. Please see my drawing to make sure we're on the same page: https://i.imgur.com/O9J9awQ.png You can see that air trying to come in through the AAV must push through the standing water, which is a restriction. And if food solids accumulate, that certainly cannot be good! I must be misunderstanding what you mean by "loop"... Can you please correct me?

Comment: @EdBeal - I understand the pros of the loop, but I'm not understanding why the cons are acceptable. Can you confirm that my diagram is correct and that the water/oils/food particles are not an issue to air flow in from the AAV? http://i.imgur.com/O9J9awQ.png

Comment: Your image has a trap my loop is above the trap and won't hold standing water. It is Basicly an air buffer that further reduces any gurgling as the AAV has a slight cracking pressure the additional loop area above the trap really helps.

Comment: @EdBeal - My appologies but I'm not familiar with plumbing. Do you mean to put the AAV at the top of this (instead of the vent on the side like in the image)? http://enacademic.com/pictures/enwiki/67/Chicago_loop_plumbing_01.png That is my best guess as to what a "loop" looks like.

Comment: That loop is different but you have the idea. The way I was taught was to t off above the trap then go both left and right 90 on both sides going up and both sides at the top 90 again to a t at a point to put the AAV in it may be necessary to have the valve to 1 side. This air loop even if for a small bar sink in an island really assist the AAV it takes a little bit of room but the advantage is no gurgling and it helps prevent water backup because of the extra air space.